# Replace array value with new one

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, reference

I have array of array, where i want to change date format. I am trying to get it as below

```
foreach ($toReturn as $value) {

    $start_date = new DateTime($value['start_date']);
    $value['start_date'] = $start_date->format('m-d-Y');

    $end_date = new DateTime($value['end_date']);
    $value['end_date'] = $end_date->format('m-d-Y');
}
```

here format gets changed but it is not replacing array value with new one?? Why??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the refrence operator `&` to change in the original array otherwise PHP treats it as local aary which is diffrent from the original one and the changes in that local array will not reflects to original array.

```
foreach ($toReturn as &$value) {

    $start_date = new DateTime($value['start_date']);
    $value['start_date'] = $start_date->format('m-d-Y');

    $end_date = new DateTime($value['end_date']);
    $value['end_date'] = $end_date->format('m-d-Y');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your want to change the value in the foreach, you need to access it by reference.

change `foreach ($toReturn as $value)` to `foreach ($toReturn as &$value)`

Comment: perfect ..Thanks.... But why it so?? i can do it for object but not for array ???Why??

Answer (score 3):

You have to change value by reference:

```
foreach ($toReturn as &$value) {

    $start_date = new DateTime($value['start_date']);
    $value['start_date'] = $start_date->format('m-d-Y');

    $end_date = new DateTime($value['end_date']);
    $value['end_date'] = $end_date->format('m-d-Y');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, if you do not wish to use the "Pass by reference" method, you can use this, or even create new variable.

```
foreach ($toReturn as $key => $value) {

    $start_date = new DateTime($value['start_date']);
    $toReturn[$key]['start_date'] = $start_date->format('m-d-Y');

    $end_date = new DateTime($value['end_date']);
    $toReturn[$key]['end_date'] = $end_date->format('m-d-Y');
}
```

**Note**: *If you wish to use pass by reference,* do not forget to unset($value) after the loop **which is not necessary for given example**.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use access `$toReturn[$index]`

```
foreach ($toReturn as $index => $value) {

    $start_date = new DateTime($value['start_date']);
    $toReturn[$index]['start_date'] = $start_date->format('m-d-Y');

    $end_date = new DateTime($value['end_date']);
    $toReturn[$index]['end_date'] = $end_date->format('m-d-Y');
}
```